# Selecting from a slowly changing dimension type II

Tags: sql, type-2-dimension

I am having trouble with a slowly changing dimension type II selection. I am looking to select the actual length of an employees skill certification so that i can display start and end of his certification in a report. How would you go about doing that? Below i have included an image of the records for an employee '80844' and below the records the expected result.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

[image: Records an employee 80844 and the expected result needed to display his certification]

Comment: What type of DB are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I don't get how the result is determined. Why is in the first row of the result the end date 2012-04-01?

Comment: @tombom, the first line in the result combines line 2,3,4 into the first line in the result because their date intervals are consecutive.

Comment: @tombom, the second line in the result begins on the 6th which is why it is not added to the first line

Comment: May I ask then, why on earth those rows are inserted? Why don't you store it in one row with start 1900-01-01 and end 2012-04-01? Maybe you should work on your ETL. When there is not really a change, leave the row as it is. Mark the up-to-date row with end date being NULL.

Comment: Why do you need overlap records as your result.It's against SCD-2 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for interesting question. It is well-known 'gaps and islands' problem. You can read more about it [there](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf).

For your case solution could look like this:

```
    create table #tmp 
       (
         dimEmployeeID int not null,
         EmployeeNumber int not null,
         Start datetime not null,
         [End] datetime not null,
         SkillID int not null
       )


   insert into #tmp values
     (386 , 80844, '1900-01-01', '2012-02-28', 14),
     (1172, 80844, '2012-02-29', '2012-02-29', 14),
     (1173, 80844, '2012-03-01', '2012-04-01', 14),
     (1175, 80844, '2012-04-06', '2012-04-12', 14),
     (1176, 80844, '2012-04-13', '2012-04-21', 14),
     (1172, 80844, '2012-02-29', '2012-02-29', 87),
     (1173, 80844, '2012-03-01', '2012-04-01', 87),
     (1174, 80844, '2012-04-02', '2012-04-05', 87),
     (1175, 80844, '2012-04-06', '2012-04-12', 87)

   ;with StartingPoints as
   (
     SELECT EmployeeNumber, SkillID, Start, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by EmployeeNumber,    SkillID order by Start asc) AS rn
     FROM #tmp AS A
     WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (
         SELECT 1
         FROM #tmp AS B
         WHERE 
           A.EmployeeNumber = B.EmployeeNumber
           and A.SkillID = B.SkillID
           and A.Start - 1 = B.[End]
        )
   ),
   EndingPoints AS
   (
     SELECT EmployeeNumber, SkillID, [End], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by EmployeeNumber,    SkillID order by Start asc) AS rn
     FROM #tmp AS A
     WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (
         SELECT 1
         FROM #tmp AS B
         WHERE 
           A.EmployeeNumber = B.EmployeeNumber
           and A.SkillID = B.SkillID
           and A.[End] + 1 = B.Start
        )
   )
   SELECT S.EmployeeNumber, S.SkillID, S.Start, E.[End]
   FROM StartingPoints AS S
     JOIN EndingPoints AS E
   ON 
     S.EmployeeNumber = E.EmployeeNumber
     and S.SkillID = E.SkillID
     and S.rn = E.rn
```